# Icon list for social media html css

Tags: css, icons, background-image

I am trying a list with social media icons in. I wanted to use nth child: but no IE support, so I am using the below method. I doesn't work though, any suggestions - no display of icons?

```
ul.socialmedia {
color: #000000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li.fb {
background:url('images/Facebook_icon.png') 50%    50% no-repeat no-repeat;
padding-left: 10px;
}

li.gp {
background:url('images/googleplus_icon.png') 50% 50% no-repeat no-repeat;
padding-left: 10px;
}

li.tw {
background:url('images/twitter-icon.png') 50% 50%  no-repeat no-repeat;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<ul class="socialmedia">
<li class="fb"><strong>FACEBOOK</strong></li>
<li class="gp"><strong>GOOGLE+</strong></li>
<li class="tw"><strong>TWITTER</strong></li>
</ul>
```

All images work and have been tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you're specifying the `background-repeat` property twice which is invalid CSS, though those properties will be ignored its best to remove them.

The problem is likely with your `background-position` values .. since you have not specified a width on your `<ul>` (its a block element, by default it takes up all available width) using 50% 50% is placing your bg-image half the width of the viewport which means it appears outside of your `<ul>` even though it technically isn't. Give a fixed width to your `<ul>` so the background-images are relative to that fixed container, not the whole viewport.

Comment: I added a width to <ul> also changed css to generic padding: 10px 0px 24px 40px; to fit in how I'd like it, and added a background-repeat:no-repeat; this then worked fine! TX for your help